# ¿Cómo obtener el sha o md5 de los archivos del servidor usando PHP?

Tags: php, sha1, md5

Quisiera saber si conoce algún método que por medio de PHP se pueda obtener la suma de verificación de los archivos alojados en el servidor y posiblemente me permita guardar la lista en un archivo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con http://php.net/manual/es/function.hash-file.php ?

Comment: Para el md5 la función es http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Answer (score 0):

Esto igual te vale:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("hash.md5", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $dir = "./"; // Directorio a escanear
    if(!is_dir($dir)) exit(); // Si no es correcto, salir
    $d = dir($dir);
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) { // Recorrer el directorio
        if(!($entry == "." || $entry == "..")) {
            fwrite($myfile, $entry . ":" . md5_file($dir . '/' . $entry) . "\n");
        }
    }
    $d->close();
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```